# How do I make a navigation drawer in the left and menu icon on the right?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have tried every option of the android:showAsAction, and it didn't work!
I think that maybe I can't get the concept of how to do it.

my app

[image]

how I want it

[image]

Comment: post you relevant code..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cart"
        android:title="Refresh"/>
    <item
        Your items
    </item>

</menu>
```

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html